# error in xml parsing in android application

Tags: android

I am implementing sax xml parsing and showing all the data in the list.The url is 
http://www.harpreetvirk.com/PMEvents/PMe.svc/providers

In it i have 3 countries.I have to implement like when user clicks on usa tags of usa should come,when user clicks on canada , tags of canada should come.Currently when i run my code it is showing all the countries,and also repeating the countries.

Below is my java class code
http://pastebin.com/MVB9VHBk

can anyone guide me how to implement this

Regards
Tushar

Comment: Its my my xml handler java code http://pastebin.com/NPNAA8eB

Comment: What do you mean by "clicks on usa tags of usa should come"? And what errors are you getting? Any logcat output pls

Comment: @paresh,,,,i want that when user clicks on usa only tags defined in us should come,,,means specific country...Currently when i run the code,,Its showing 9 countries,,,ie repeating,,,

Comment: Please don't post links to external pastebins or similar. Make a short piece of code illustrating your problem and embed it into your question.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ,,can u solve my issue,,???

Comment: No, I can't, edit your question to add in the required code and flag it for reopening, or reply here, it'll get into my inbox and I'll reopen it, but add the required code first.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen do u have skype ?

Comment: I cannot help you, I don't do android programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *characters* function in *MyXMLHandler* you can check the value of *ch* because sometimes the *characters* is called multiple times implicitly by android with empty value in *ch*. I faced such problem today only and also a few months ago.

Comment: ,,can u open the url..I have to do like this,,,There are 3 countries.When user clicks on usa tags of only usa should be shown...